# Bootstrap 4: estilos diferentes segun el navegador

Tags: css, bootstrap, select, firefox

Tengo un sitio diseñado usando AdminLte 3.2, el cual viene integrado con bootstap4. Mi problema esta relacionado específicamente con los estilos de los `<select>`. Visualizando el sitio con Firefox, las opciones del `<select>` aparecen en negrita, mientras que en Chrome, Opera y Palemoon aparecen en estilo normal, por lo que pienso que puede estar relacionado con la forma en que Firefox interpreta los estilos. ¿Alguna idea de por qué sucede esto y cómo solucionarlo?

En Chrome, Opera, Palemoon:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Firefox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides mostrar un [repro]. Menciona qué clases se están utilizando en ese select.

Comment: Accedí desde Firefox a [la página demo de AdminLTE 3](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/forms/general.html), y se muestran los selects tal como en la primera imagen de tu pregunta.

Comment: @padaleiana Esto puede convertirse en un argumento del tipo "en mi máquina si funciona", pues con mi copia local de AdminLTE y con la que se encuentra en internet, en ambas obtengo el mismo resultado que el mostrado en las imágenes. La codificación es exactamente la misma que la original (no uso estilos personales que afecten los campos de los formularios) y la hoja de estilo de AdminLTE es la última a la que hago referencia en la declaración de los estilos.